# How to remove comma in the input text form using JS before it will be submitted to the server?

Tags: javascript

I have a form that when submitted to the server will contain commas in the query string values, for example:

```
 test.com/?manufacturer=0&body-style=0&min-price=270%2C000&max-price=780%2C000
```

Is there a way to remove this comma using JS just after the user clicks the form but before it will be submitted to the server? I have this approach here: [How replace query string values using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338956/how-replace-query-string-values-using-jquery)

But that will only change the text to integer but in the URL itself. I also tried using input number attribute in HTML 5 but I cannot figure out how to use a comma by default to show it on the form: [How to force to display a number with a comma with input type number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341325/how-to-force-to-display-a-number-with-a-comma-with-input-type-number)

I would appreciate any tips. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Final working solution:

```
$('.my_form').submit(function() {

var x=$('#input_text_field_one').val();
x=x.replace(/,/g,'');
x=parseInt(x,10);
$('#input_text_field_one').val(x);

return true;

});
```

input_text_field_one is the input text form containing a number with commas.
.my_form is the class name for the form. After form submit the above code replace the numbers with commas to without commas. So finally, the numbers are submitted as number. :)

Comment: what's the problem exactly ? why can't you just take care of the eventual commas server-side ? What if at some point the value after the comma is not 0 ?

Comment: Yes this is easy server side but it's a plugin that is beyond my control. I don't want to edit the plugin core source code because I'm not allowed. And there are no hooks to override.

Comment: Final solution that works I posted it on my question..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want something like this:-

```
form.onSubmit = function(){
   form.action = form.action.replace(",", "");
   return true;
}
```